# Empty list for variable when I use solve() in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, calculus, calc

I tried reading other posts that mentioned this problem and I couldn't understand how to apply them to my situation. Also this is my first time using stack overflow, so I apologize for any formatting errors.

```
from sympy import *
from math import sqrt
x = symbols('x')
a = symbols('a',positive=True)
f = 1 / ((x**4)*((x**2)-(a**2))**.5)
#Part A
g = f.subs(4*a,x)
h = f.subs(2*a,x)
area=g-h
#Part B
answ = solve(area-5,a)
print ('part a:' , str(area))
print ('part b:' , str(answ[0].evalf()))
```

I'm trying to get a value to print out.

I also have the same issue in this code block

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
# Part A
f = (x**3-4*x+3) / (((x-5)**2)*(x**2+3)*(x**2+5))
print("The partial fraction decomposition of f is :", apart(f), "\n")

# Part B
a = symbols('a', positive=True, constant=True)
g = (x**2+2*x+a) / (x-1)**3*(x**2+1)
print("The partial fraction decomposition of g is :", apart(g, x), "\n")

# Part C
g = apart(g, x)
G1 = integrate(x, (x, 2, 4))
G2 = integrate(2*(a + 3)/(x - 1)**3, (x, 2, 4))
G3 = integrate(2 * (a + 7) / (x - 1)**2, (x, 2, 4))
G4 = integrate((a + 13)/(x - 1), (x, 2, 4))
G5 = integrate(5, (x, 2, 4))
print(G1, G2, G3, G4, G5)
value = solve((G1 + G2 + G3 + G4 + G5 - 1), a)

print((value))
```

Since a couple people seemed confused, [here](http://calclab.math.tamu.edu/Python/Math152Lab4a.pdf) are the problems I am trying to solve with python.

Comment: Where are you giving the values for `x` and `a`?

Comment: @bigbounty I don't exactly know what you mean, here are the questions that I am trying to solve with Python though if that helps! http://calclab.math.tamu.edu/Python/Math152Lab4a.pdf

Comment: But I thought the substitution that I did on line 7 & 8 took care of that

Comment: if you check the values for f, g, h you'll find that they are all equal. Your substitutions aren't matching anything in f, so g and h are just being set equal to f. Then when you do g-h, the result is 0.

Comment: So what should I do instead @J.Taylor? This is my first time using sympy.

Comment: I have no idea - I don't understand the math. I just ran your code, and can only tell you why it's broken :) ... I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your substitutions there for `g` and `h` but if you check the value of `f`, you get `(-a**2 + x**2)**(-0.5)/x**4` ... so when you do `g = f.subs(4*a,x)`, where is the `4*a` that you are trying to replace with `x`? It's not there, so since nothing gets replaced, you're essentially just doing `g=f` (and likewise for `h`)

Comment: Oh! I see, I'll try fixing that. I posted in a previous comment a link to the problems that I'm trying to solve if that gives you better context. I'll update you @J.Taylor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out after talking to my TA for a little bit, if anyone is curious I am going to post the solutions and explanations here with it.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import (plot, plot_parametric,plot3d_parametric_surface, plot3d_parametric_line, plot3d)
```

part of the issue was importing math for the sqrt() function because it conflicted with sympy's, thereby making it impossible to solve anything.

```
# Insert code for problem #1 here.
x = symbols('x')
a = symbols('a', positive=True)
f = 1 / ((x**4)*(sqrt((x**2)-(a**2))))
#Part A
F = integrate(f, x)
g = F.subs(x, 4*a)
h = F.subs(x, 2*a)
area = g - h
#Part B
# print(area.evalf())
answ = solve(area-5, a)
print ('part a:', area)
print ('part b:', answ[0].evalf())
```

The next group of problems was that I mis-used the subs() function, placing the variable I wanted to solve for on the wrong side. I also integrated the function before hand, in order to actually solve for the area under the curve. In order to get a value for answ I used the first value of the vector created along with the evalf() to aproximate it.

```
# Insert code for problem #3 here.
x = symbols('x')
# Part A
f = (x**3-4*x+3) / (((x-5)**2)*(x**2+3)*(x**2+5))
print("The partial fraction decomposition of f is :", apart(f), "\n")
# Part B
a = symbols('a', positive=True)
g = (x**2+2*x+a) / ((x-1)**3*(x**2+1))
print("The partial fraction decomposition of g is :", apart(g, x), "\n")
# Part C
g = apart(g, x)
# print(g)
# G = integrate(g, (x,2,4))
G1 = integrate((a - 3)/(4*(x - 1)), (x, 2, 4))
G2 = integrate((a - 1)/(2*(x - 1)**2), (x, 2, 4))
G3 = integrate((a + 3)/(2*(x - 1)**3), (x, 2, 4))
G4 = integrate((a*x-3*x)/(4*(x**2 + 1)) , (x, 2, 4))
G5 = integrate((-a-1)/(4*(x**2 + 1)), (x, 2, 4))
value = solve((G1- G2 + G3 - G4- G5 - 1), a)
print("\n", "The answer for part C is:",(value[0].evalf()))
```

The problem with the next grouping of the code was some simple syntax errors on the g(x) function. I also had to remove the constant=True, this was because it made solving for a impossible.

Comment: I have come across the same situation. Minimum working example: 
```import sympy as sym
x = sym.symbols('x', constant=True) # constant=False also produces empty set`  
y = sym.symbols('y', constant=True)  
x_y_eq = sym.Eq(x + y, 0)           # x + y = 0  
display(sym.solve(x_y_eq, x))       # empty set  
# redefine x - remove constant=True  
x = sym.symbols('x')
x_y_eq = sym.Eq(x + y, 0)           # x + y = 0  
display(sym.solve(x_y_eq, x))       # x = -y   (expected result)  
```
  
Is this the expected or designed behavior for sympy?